# how to use SSL pining in every Api request using http plugin fllutter

Tags: flutter, sslpinning

I am new to SSL pinning, I was asked to use SSL pinning in every API request. I checked some resources but I didn't get the idea of how to call it in my API request.
I am using HTTP/HTTP plugin and not Dio, if anyone can provide me an example of how to use it in the API request? or how to use it?

Thank you in advance